# Type of window.location

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to read the page Url with the URL object.

```
let url:URL = new URL(window.location)
```

This returns an error `Argument of type 'Location' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

```
let url:Location = new URL(window.location)
```

This instead returns `Type 'URL' is missing the following properties from type 'Location': ancestorOrigins, assign, reload, replace`

So what's the type of an URL object?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is not related to the type of `let url`. The problem is that according to TypeScript `new URL()` expects a string but you give it a `Location` object. This would work in plain JavaScript because the Location is going to be converted to a string.

In order to satisfy the compiler you need to be more explicit and pass a string to the constructor:

```js
let url: URL = new URL(window.location.href);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBArgTsBcECqAlAMhAvBAdiA7sugBT4CWOAJgPb4B0w1AxgIZhnU50AWMIAZgEoA3EA)